# Anaconda Spyder to measure data burst start and end time

Tags: python, data-visualization, spyder

I have a one dimensional array of data (complex samples) consisting of many data bursts lined up in this array. I tried to visualize the start time and end time for each burst using the plot function. However, since the number of data samples are huge, this freezes my PC. Is there an efficient way to do this using Anaconda / Python Spyder?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post what you've tried and the result you're getting as well as your desired output?

Comment: I only tried to read the data via a plot, but the plot freezes due to the huge number of samples in the data set. I think there should be a better way to find out all these bursts' start and end times in the data set.